# Check If button has class and then show a div

Tags: jquery

How can I check if the button has a class?

For example: If the button has class `btn-success` then show div `.success-message`. Else if the button has class `btn-danger` then show div `.danger-message`.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/brunodd/fs1rnydc/)

```
$(".btn-disapear").click(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    $(this).closest(".panel").animate({opacity: 0}, 500).slideUp(400, function() {
        $(".success-message").fadeIn(400, function() {
            $(this).delay(900).fadeOut(400);
        });    
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to put if statements after the click statement

```
$(".btn-disapear").click(function() {
var $this = $(this);
$(this).closest(".panel").animate({opacity: 0}, 500).slideUp(400, function() {
    if($this.hasClass("btn-success")){
    $(".success-message").fadeIn(400, function() {
        $(this).delay(900).fadeOut(400);
    });
}
else{
$(".danger-message").fadeIn(400, function() {
        $(this).delay(900).fadeOut(400);
    });
   }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

[$.hasClass()](https://api.jquery.com/hasclass/) its what you are looking for

```
$this.hasClass( "danger-message" )
```

it would look something like this

```
$(".btn-disapear").click(function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    $(this).closest(".panel").animate({
        opacity: 0
    }, 500).slideUp(400, function () {
        if ($this.hasClass("btn-success")) {
            $(".success-message").fadeIn(400, function () {
                $(this).delay(900).fadeOut(400);
            });
        } else if ($this.hasClass("btn-danger")) {
            $(".danger-message").fadeIn(400, function () {
                $(this).delay(900).fadeOut(400);
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [**hasClass**](https://api.jquery.com/hasclass/)

```
var message = $this.hasClass('btn-success') ? '.success-message' : '.danger-message';
```

```js
$(".btn-disapear").click(function() {
  var $this = $(this);
  var message = $this.hasClass('btn-success') ? '.success-message' : '.danger-message';
  $(this).closest(".panel").animate({
    opacity: 0
  }, 500).slideUp(400, function() {
    $(message).fadeIn(400, function() {
      $(this).delay(900).fadeOut(400);
    });

  });
});
```

```css
.show-message {
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 70px;
}
.message {
  width: 100%;
  height: 30px;
  color: #fff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 99;
  line-height: 30px;
  display: none;
}
.success-message {
  background: #27ae60;
  display: none;
}
.danger-message {
  background: #e74c3c;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container show-message">
  <div class="message success-message text-center">
    <p>Green message</p>
  </div>

  <div class="message danger-message text-center">
    <p>Red message</p>
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-8 offset-md-2">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">Panel</div>
      <div class="panel-body">
        <a class="btn btn-disapear btn-success pull-left" href="#" role="button">Show green message</a>

        <a class="btn btn-disapear btn-danger pull-right" href="#" role="button">Show red message</a>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">Panel</div>
      <div class="panel-body">
        <a class="btn btn-disapear btn-success pull-left" href="#" role="button">Show green message</a>

        <a class="btn btn-disapear btn-danger pull-right" href="#" role="button">Show red message</a>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading text-bold">Panel</div>
      <div class="panel-body">
        <a class="btn btn-disapear btn-success pull-left" href="#" role="button">Show green message</a>

        <a class="btn btn-disapear btn-danger pull-right" href="#" role="button">Show red message</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

or [**is()**](https://api.jquery.com/is/)

```
var message = $this.is('.btn-success') ? '.success-message' : '.danger-message';
```

```js
$(".btn-disapear").click(function() {
  var $this = $(this);
  var message = $this.is('.btn-success') ? '.success-message' : '.danger-message';
  $(this).closest(".panel").animate({
    opacity: 0
  }, 500).slideUp(400, function() {
    $(message).fadeIn(400, function() {
      $(this).delay(900).fadeOut(400);
    });

  });
});
```

```css
.show-message {
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 70px;
}
.message {
  width: 100%;
  height: 30px;
  color: #fff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 99;
  line-height: 30px;
  display: none;
}
.success-message {
  background: #27ae60;
  display: none;
}
.danger-message {
  background: #e74c3c;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container show-message">
  <div class="message success-message text-center">
    <p>Green message</p>
  </div>

  <div class="message danger-message text-center">
    <p>Red message</p>
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-8 offset-md-2">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">Panel</div>
      <div class="panel-body">
        <a class="btn btn-disapear btn-success pull-left" href="#" role="button">Show green message</a>

        <a class="btn btn-disapear btn-danger pull-right" href="#" role="button">Show red message</a>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">Panel</div>
      <div class="panel-body">
        <a class="btn btn-disapear btn-success pull-left" href="#" role="button">Show green message</a>

        <a class="btn btn-disapear btn-danger pull-right" href="#" role="button">Show red message</a>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading text-bold">Panel</div>
      <div class="panel-body">
        <a class="btn btn-disapear btn-success pull-left" href="#" role="button">Show green message</a>

        <a class="btn btn-disapear btn-danger pull-right" href="#" role="button">Show red message</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use CSS? Something like:

```
.btn-disapear.btn-success .success-message {
    display:block;
}

.btn-disapear.btn-danger .danger-message {
    display:block;
}
```